# rsync as root - does it change the ownership of synced files?

Tags: rsync, backup, root

I'm going to be using rsync to sync an old home folder onto a backup drive. I'm thinking of using rsync as root. Is there a way to avoid changing the ownership of the files etc I copy?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-o` and `-g` options. From [the `rsync` manual (`man rsync`)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> `-o`, `--owner`                 preserve owner (super-user only)
>
> `-g`, `--group`                 preserve group

Going one step further, an option commonly used with `rsync` is the `-a`/`--archive` option. This option implies `-rlptgoD`, which are the following options:

> `-r`, `--recursive`             recurse into directories
>
> `-l`, `--links`                 copy symlinks as symlinks
>
> `-p`, `--perms`                 preserve permissions
>
> `-t`, `--times`                 preserve modification times
>
> `-D`                          same as `--devices --specials` (preserve device files, preserve special files)

Comment: I'm not a big fan of -a. Back when I used Cygwin, it mw

Comment: It messed up a bunch of file's I was trying to do this same thing with. Of course Cygwin's rsync was probably the same as the one from BSD (I know its tar w

Comment: I know its tar was.

Comment: @SteveWright, I have a good experience of the `-a` option. I use it often for home directories, even as part of the `mkusb` tool for persistent live drives.

Comment: A also with Cygwin, it didn't help that NTFS, while somewhat close to one, still isn't a Lunix filesystem.

Comment: @SteveWright, You point to the problem: NTFS in linux cannot manage file permissions individually. All the permissions are set when mounted, and are the same for all directories and files. I think there are problems with some special files too. So if you backup to an NTFS file system, you had better use a container, for example a [compressed] `tar` archive, a tarball. As with `rsync`, you should use elevated permissions, `sudo`, in order to manage files of other users in `/home` and of course of the system files, owned by `root`.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following command line to preserve 'everything', file content, ownership and permissions of files, directories, symbolic links etc. This way I have been able to copy a system to a new drive and make it work in another computer. OK, I had to fix the bootloader too, but it works well with copying of the file content, ownership and permissions.

- Please notice the trailing slash on the source directory, and read about it in `man rsync`.

> ```
>           rsync -avz foo:src/bar/ /data/tmp
>
>    A  trailing slash on the source changes this behavior to avoid creating
>    an additional directory level at the destination.  You can think  of  a
>    trailing / on a source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory"
>    as opposed to "copy the directory by  name",  but  in  both  cases  the
>    attributes  of the containing directory are transferred to the contain‐
>    ing directory on the destination.  In other words, each of the  follow‐
>    ing  commands copies the files in the same way, including their setting
>    of the attributes of /dest/foo:
>
>           rsync -av /src/foo /dest
>           rsync -av /src/foo/ /dest/foo
>
>    Note also that host and module  references  don’t  require  a  trailing
>    slash to copy the contents of the default directory.  For example, both
>    of these copy the remote directory’s contents into "/dest":
>
>           rsync -av host: /dest
>           rsync -av host::module /dest
>
>    You can also use rsync in local-only mode, where both  the  source  and
>    destination  don’t have a ’:’ in the name. In this case it behaves like
>    an improved copy command.
> ```

- `-n`, start with a 'dry run', to check that things look correct.

  ```
  sudo rsync -Havn source/ target
  ```
- Remove the option (`-n`) and let `rsync` do its job.

  ```
  sudo rsync -Hav source/ target
  ```

It will check if each directory/file in the target exists and is up to date, and only copy what needs to be updated (in a backup scenario).

---

- `-H` keeps track of hard links (which save drive space), but makes the copy process slower (the reason that it is not included in `-a`
- `-a` is the standard archive option for backup purposes, which preserves 'everything' about the files in the file system (except hard links).
- `-v` is the classic verbose option, which prints all files that are to be copied. There are other options to monitor the progress, that you may like better. You may prefer to turn off verbosity, but it is good in the early stages to check that things work are expected.

Comment: I like it. I think I'll go with it.

Comment: @SteveWright, Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
sudo rsync -HavE /SOURCE /DEST
```

since I have executable bash .sh scripts in the backup.

The acroynm `-HavE  is good for remembering "HavEverything"

The acroynm `-HavEn` is good for remembering "HavEverything" safely

-E, --executability     preserve executability

Thanks for the answer @sudodus

Kevin